# What's wrong with these sentences?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

> 1. Either of the two resolutions are made by me.
> 2. Working out, as well as reading, are some ways to release stress.

It says the subject-verb agreements in the following sentences are incorrect.
These sentences seem fine to me.
Could you please explain what's wrong and why?

Source: from a Complete Canadian Curriculum book, in the English section.

Comment: Could you add the source of these examples?

Comment: There. I edited.

Comment: I'm thinking that you probably ought to get yourself a better grammar book. :)

Comment: Why? What's wrong with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both sentences the predicate should be "is". The rules are the following: if the subject is expressed by either of, none of, neither of we use a singular verb as we mean one item ( "either of" meaning "either this or that one"), in the second sentence we have "as well as", the sentence can be rephrased: working out just like reading ( we compare two things, but caracterise one of them, the first one, so the predicate agrees with it, if it' s singular the verb is singular and if plural it requires a plural verb

Comment: Could you please add some grammar sources to show where those "rules" could be found?

Comment: "None of them **are**" is actually quite common, more common than "none of them **is**"; see [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=34036325).

Comment: "Either of the two resolutions is/are made by me." This sentence sounds unnatural to me regardless of the verb chosen. It works with 'neither ... is/are" or "Both ... are", but not really with "Either ... is/are".

Comment: @tunny I agree the first sentence is strange. "Either of the two options is acceptable to me." or "Either of the two resolutions could be made by me." would make more sense.

Comment: I found [a web page](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sv_agr.htm) that explains the subject verb agreement rules and explains that `In informal writing, neither and either sometimes take a plural verb when these pronouns are followed by a prepositional phrase beginning with of. This is particularly true of interrogative constructions`

Comment: Then what are the correct ways of saying these sentences?